# How to get the percentage of a coordinate between two lines (Highcharts -spline)

Tags: javascript, html, css, graph, highcharts

im still new in using Highcharts for create a graph. First, sorry for my bad English. And here i attach a picture that describe my problem: 
[image]

as you can see, i had assign or label each line with percentage.
for example:
red line - 5%, blue line- 25%, green line- 50%, black line- 75%, yellow line- 97%.

it means that, any new point (data) that touch on any of the line is consider as the percentage stated. In this case, orange marker(label as "test") is on black line, so, it is consider as 75%. So, my question is, is it possible to get the percentage, if the new point is not on any of the line. In this case, the pink marker(label as "my percentage") is between on black line and yellow line.

```
This is the graph on jsfiddle
```

http://jsfiddle.net/syafieqq/usg5uzmL/2/

all data of the colored lines is obtain from:
https://www.cdc.gov/growthcharts/html_charts/wtageinf.htm

TQ..

Comment: From what I can see, the graph is presenting statistical data for weight of children in range from 0 to 25 months of life. Each line shows how many children (expressed in percentage) have a specific body weight in a specific age. The 'My percentage' marker represents specific weight value but it is hard to say how many children belong to the group. Maybe there is an equation which calculate this but you need to find it by yourself and it has nothing to do with Highcharts.

Comment: Important to note that this is a `percentile` measurement, as opposed to a `percentage`. Figuring out what `weight percentile` a child falls at is not a matter of measuring how close to each line it is, it's a matter of comparing the weight to the distribution from which the statistics have been generated. Not only is it "nothing to do with Highcharts", as @d_paul indicated, using the chart or it's limited data to calculate it will end with erroneous results.